# How to make the height of dropdown menu same as the height of submenu in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, multi-level

I am making a navbar with multi level drop down menu. I want to make the height of drop-down menu same as the height of sub-menu.

**Like This:**

[image: Like This]

When the sub-menu is hidden, the drop-down menu will return the original size.
**Like This:**
[image: Like This]
Here is my code

```css
.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  right: 3px;
  top: 40%;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-submenu:focus .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  min-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light ">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            
            </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown link
                    </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu top">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>


            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted? I added a class `.add-to-ul` and a class `.add-to-dropdown-div` at, well the name says it. And gave it some styles.

Also I added an ID to the `nav` so I can style the bootstrap elements easier.

```css
.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  right: 3px;
  top: 40%;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-submenu:focus .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  min-height: 200%;
}

#bootstrap-edits .add-to-ul{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

#bootstrap-edits .add-to-dropdown-div{
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light " id="bootstrap-edits">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            
            </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown link
                    </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu add-to-ul" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu top add-to-dropdown-div">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>


            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. The result is not completely my wanted.  I want the drop-down menu will auto match the height of sub-menu.

Comment: it does now right? if you add another A or b to it the menu will also get longer to match the same height.

Comment: I add another a or b to the submenu. The drop-down menu would not auto match the height of sub-menu. Also, the navbar will expand, when i click the drop-down menu.